# Утечка памяти при работе с LPSTREAM в GDIplus::Bitmap::Save()

Tags: c++, winapi, утечка-памяти, gdi+

Ниже заранее предоставляю свой код.

Вся проблема состоит в неполной очистке памяти `LPSTREAM` после использования в `GDIplus::Bitmap::Save()`

Конкретно в этой строке:

```
bmp->Save(stream, &jpegClsid, &encoderParameters);
```

После возврата из функции считываю содержимое потока и пытаюсь его очистить с помощью

```
str->Release();
```

но память не очищается, на скриншоте вызовы функции TakeScreenshot:

(Скачки использования памяти при сохраненении в HBITMAP, чистый скриншот весит 14мб, так как снимок 2х экранов)

[image: Screenshot]

Может я что-то упустил в остальном коде?

Потратил на эту проблему целые сутки, ткните носом в ошибку, пожалуйста.

```
void SaveJpeg(HBITMAP hbmpImage, unsigned int Quality, LPSTREAM stream)
{
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

Gdiplus::EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
encoderParameters.Count = 1;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = Gdiplus::EncoderQuality;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = Gdiplus::EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;

encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &Quality;

CLSID jpegClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &jpegClsid);
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(hbmpImage, (HPALETTE)0);

//bmp->Save(L"1.jpg", &jpegClsid, &encoderParameters);
bmp->Save(stream, &jpegClsid, &encoderParameters);
delete(bmp);

}

void WINAPI TakeScreenshot(unsigned int quality, LPBYTE* fs, ULONG* written)
{
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);

SelectObject(hDest, hbDesktop);

BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

LPSTREAM str;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, FALSE, &str);
SaveJpeg(hbDesktop, quality, str);
STATSTG Stat;
if (str->Stat(&Stat, STATFLAG_NONAME) == S_OK && Stat.cbSize.HighPart == 0)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.HighPart = 0;
    li.LowPart = 0;
    str->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
    LPBYTE buf = (LPBYTE)malloc(sizeof(DWORD) + Stat.cbSize.LowPart);

    if (buf != NULL)
    {
        if (str->Read(buf + sizeof(DWORD), Stat.cbSize.LowPart, &Stat.cbSize.LowPart) == S_OK)
        {
            *((LPDWORD)buf) = Stat.cbSize.LowPart;
            *fs = buf;
            *written = sizeof(DWORD) + Stat.cbSize.LowPart;
        }

    }
    free(buf);
}
str->Release();

ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

DeleteDC(hDest);
}
```

Comment: Для 'hbDesktop' вроде как нужен 'DeleteObject'

Comment: Добавил, спасибо. Но это конечно же не решает проблему с очисткой потока.

Answer (score 4):

Все оказалось довольно просто.

Нужно было заменить FALSE в

```
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, FALSE, &str);
```

На TRUE.

Этот параметр определяет, нужно ли очищать память потока после вызова

```
stream->Release();
```